# how to delete every files extracted after extracting and doing required tasks?

Tags: python

how to delete every files extracted after extracting doing required tasks?

```
files = glob.glob('*.tar.gz')

for f in files:
    with tarfile.open(f, 'r:gz') as tar:
        tar.extractall()
```

I want to delete those extracted files here.

os.remove() can be used, but i want to feed up the name of the files automatically through the first extracting process. how is it possible?

Comment: how about extract them to some temp folders?

Comment: @zhangxaochen i have to extract the files first in the same directory whiere the source file exists.

Comment: @zhangxaochen i want to feed up the name of the files automatically through the first extracting process. how is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[shutil.rmtree()](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)  deletes a directory and all of its contents.

[os.remove()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove)  deletes a file.

[os.rmdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rmdir)  deletes an empty directory

Wherever those files get extracted, use the above functions to delete them.

```
import os
files = glob.glob('*.tar.gz')

for f in files:
    with tarfile.open(f, 'r:gz') as tar:
        tar.extractall()
        extracted_files = os.listdir(".") #retrieves the lists of all files and folders in the current directory
        for file in extracted_files:
            if file.endswith(".tar.gz"): # do not process tar.gz files
                continue
            absolute_path = os.path.abspath(file) # get the absolute path    
            if os.path.isdir(absolute_path): # test if the path points to a directory
                shutil.rmtree(absolute_path)
            else: # normal file
                os.remove(absolute_path)
```

Comment: os.remove() is okay but i want to feed up the name of the files automatically through the first extracting process. how is it possible?

Comment: but, i should not remove the original source file (.tar.gz)

Comment: updated the code. It ignores all the files ending in ".tar.gz"

Comment: what if the .tar.gz file contains .tar.gz files in it?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: i made that assumption that there are no .tar.gz files in .tar.gz. If it is really the case, then as you said, extract files to some temp directory and then delete that directory

Comment: @zhangxaochen: one other solution is to extract a file one by one using  TarFile.next() and TarFile.extractfile() and then delete it. This way you won't need a temp directory

Comment: It would be much better to simply read the list of files in the tar object and delete them rather than rely on the assumption that the only files in the directory are the ones extracted from this tar archive.